# Using the Instagram API and my own Access Token, why can't I get any user's data?

Tags: html, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using my own access token and calling the link `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/hacklifeprius/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

with my own access token, but I get an html page saying:

`Sorry, this page isn't available. The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed. Go back to Instagram.`

However, if I change my username to `self` then it works and I get a json. This was working last week. What's going on? By the way, I am on sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have put my Instagram user's ID number, not username.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> The first point is important and it means that **the API behaves as if the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users**, and the only media ever posted were the last 20 for each of these users.

Comment: But I am in the sandbox.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant Is hacklifeprius?

Comment: Yeah that is my account using the developer sandbox

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant If that account is the admin for the app or one of the 10 sandbox users, then your next recourse would seem to be a bug report to Instagram.